# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"? (4)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

И снова это "как"... Не могу найти правила к такому примеру:

> Ярость всегда присуща настоящему воину. И она в нем пробуждается изнутри при его оценке ситуации и выборе решения(,) как действовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*И она в нем пробуждается изнутри при его оценке ситуации и выборе решения (какого?), как (нужно) действовать.*

Запятая отделяет придаточное безличное предложение с пропуском вспомогательного глагола в составном глагольном сказуемом.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**Замечания к ответу  (для улучшения качества работы форума)**

Ответ верный, но есть замечания по точности ответа.

***Ярость всегда присуща настоящему воину. И она в нем пробуждается изнутри при оценке ситуации и выборе решения,  как действовать.***

1. **В ответе нет грамматической точности**: не указан вид придаточного, а вопрос «какой?» сюда не подходит.
2. **Запятая действительно  нужна,** но в данном случае это не кажется очевидным, в том числе интонационно запятая не прочитывается однозначно (паузу при чтении можно не делать, а в конце предложения логическим ударением выделить оборот).  Именно поэтому вопрос вызвал интерес.

Сравнить:

(1) **Решение (какое?) действовать** – это необособленное несогласованное определение, выраженное инфинитивом; запятой нет. Например: *Решение действовать я принял сразу.*

(2) **Решение, как действовать.** При наличии подчинительного союзного слова  КАК запятая ставится. **Это изъяснительное придаточное предложение** с опорным (главным) словом «решение», при этом можно дополнительно подставить указательное слово: решение **о том,** как действовать.  Придаточное односоставное, безличное.

Таким образом, оборот с КАК является **придаточным предложением,** его нельзя  считать необособленным определением.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:  *Решение, как поступить, у него составилось быстро.* [М. Н. Волконский. Воля судьбы (1914)]

3. Для сравнения. Придаточные **определительные** предложения строятся по другой схеме, например:  *То решение* (какое?)*, которое он принял, вполне устраивало его.*

Comment: "как" здесь союзное слово, а не союз. В остальном, не вижу противоречий с предыдущим ответом. Там тоже сказано про полноценное придаточное предложение.

Comment: Замечание про союзное слово принимается, однако это здесь не принципиальный вопрос. Определить вид придаточного нужно  было обязательно, иначе как доказать, что это придаточное

Comment: @Sharon  Я проголосовал за вопрос (не понимаю, зачем в данном случае хотят закрыть его, вместо того чтобы направить новичка, дать хотя бы ссылку в комментариях на похожие вопросы), проголосовал за ответ Людмилы и, конечно, за ваш ответ. Не могли бы вы пояснить (может, с логикой у меня непорядок), почему, чтобы доказать, что это придаточное, нужно обязательно определить его вид.

Comment: Спасибо за такой полный ответ! Даже как-то стыдно; сразу не сообразил, что это совсем не тот случай с "как", где рассматриваются сравнительные обороты.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что две галочки поставить нельзя?

Comment: Что я могу сказать по поводу вопросов. Специально взяла современный синтаксис, чтобы выяснить, насколько актуален вариант с вопросами.  В теме «второстепенные члены предложения» действительно такой прием используется, но только не в СПП. Там все на другом уровне, даже для придаточных определительных вопрос не задается. Вот и мне такая методика кажется слишком школьной и немного наивной.

Comment: Я думаю, что вопрос "какое?" грамматически некорректный, а правильный вопрос "о чем?". См мою загадку https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463528