# Нужна ли запятая? (7)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

> Разочарованный, он ложился обратно на матрас, смотрел вниз из-под полей соломенной шляпы и **слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи, голоса.**
> [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=eOJoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B8,%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0.&source=bl&ots=4c8QUSaNps&sig=ACfU3U02ipS0_IK9zS5iE0yiqz76HMw1YQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9noP_rNjuAhVIiIsKHQQlA7UQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0.&f=false)

Смущает постановка последней запятой в предложении. В печатном издании она стоит.
Она точно нужна?

Comment: Ормонд, такого предложения (Он слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи, голоса) в книге "Дом, в котором..." нет — это только часть. Тогда и оформлять нужно как часть цитаты. Но лучше давать предложение полностью. А ещё лучше — вместе со ссылкой.

Comment: Благодарю! Учту!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Второй ответ** (комментарий на полученный ответ и подведение иогов дискуссии)

1. Действительно, обособление оборота в такой позиции – это более **универсальная форма,** в то время как **однородные** отношения (при постановке одной запятой) **не всегда прочитываются ясно**.  Для этого случая оборот должен быть малораспространенным.
2. А в нашем примере возникает еще одна проблема – оборот грамматически может включать в себя определяемое слово, тогда он выглядит так: ***тонкие, похожие на птичьи голоса***, …  А дальше продолжения нет.  Читатель здесь должен остановиться, вернуться назад и догадаться,  что это однородные определения , поэтому читать их следует с перечислительной интонацией.

На эту проблему обратил внимание **наш новый участник,** что весьма похвально.

3. При обособлении же  четко прочитывается **первый** (основной)  план – **«тонкие голоса»,** а попутное сравнение расположено на **втором** плане речи. Получается выразительная, компактная конструкция. И вот эта **универсальная форма объявляется в ПАС ненормированной**, в то время как у Розенталя это разрешенный вариант.
4. Вообще говоря,  такие ситуации характеры для ПАС в целом, когда новые правила ухудшают читаемость и понимание смысла текста. К этим правилам нужно вообще получше приглядеться, это только со стороны кажется, что они мало отличаются от Правил Розенталя. В действительности там очень много изменений. **Упрощение, опрощение, стремление к однозначным решениям – вот что для них характерно.** Они сводят на нет мысль Розенталя **о гибкости и вариативности** русской пунктуации.
5. Отсюда делаем **вывод**. Если отвечающие пользуются преимущественно ПАС, то в спорных случаях желательно просматривать оба справочника, иначе получаются ошибочные ответы. Вернемся к вопросу: **Смущает постановка последней запятой в предложении. В печатном издании она стоит. Она точно нужна?**

И вот в полученном ответе сказано, что запятую ставить не следует, **а это неверно.**

Answer (score 3):

Оставаясь один, мальчик выходил на балкон, ложился там на надувной матрас и смотрел сквозь перила на игравших внизу ребят. Иногда вставал, чтобы его было видно. Ребята задирали головы и улыбались. Но никогда не звали спуститься. Втайне он ждал этого приглашения, но его не звали. **Разочарованный, он ложился обратно на матрас, смотрел вниз из-под полей соломенной шляпы и слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи, голоса.**

https://www.libfox.ru/611460-10-mariam-petrosyan-dom-v-kotorom-izdanie-2-e-dopolnennoe-illyustrirovannoe-2016.html

**Почему здесь стоит запятая?** Потому что ее поставил писатель! Это он составил предложение **такой структуры,** чтобы на основе своего художественного чутья выразить нужную ему мысль.

Запятая поставлена по правилам. Строгие требования предъявляются для неоднородных определений – в этом случае прилагательное не может стоять после определительного оборота, иначе структура не прочитывается. А вот **однородные и  уточняюще-пояснительные отношения заменяют друг друга.**

**Обособленный оборот прекрасно смотрится** на своем месте, однозначно читается и при этом выделен интонационно и по смыслу. Убрать запятую – это значит **грубо вмешаться** в авторскую художественную ткань.

**Но что может случиться?** Придут редакторы, прочитают инструкцию и, водя пальчиком строго по ней, решат, что запятая по Новым правилам не нужна. У них нет художественного чутья, они не понимают происхождения тех или других  правил, но могут их читать и применять. Если они даже начнут объяснять свои действия, но  будут использовать **логику компьютера:** просчитают варианты и выберут оптимальный. Но при этом из предложения **уйдет жизнь,** заложенная в него автором, оно только будет **казаться живым.**

И вот пусть эти редакторы поймут простую вещь: **любое изменение в структуре** авторского предложения (а знаки препинания непосредственно влияют на эту структуру),  **может быть губительны**м для него. Уйдут смысловые оттенки, изменится интонация и эмоциональный план.

**Поэтому не надо править авторский текст наших классиков!**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Это я работаю без правил, вы меня так плохо знаете? Я готова ответить за любое правило, о котором говорю.

Например, я пишу: **А вот однородные и  уточняюще-пояснительные отношения заменяют друг друга.** Праило не привожу, но по требованию общественности пожалуйста.

Просто я свободно могу использовать эту информацию, мне в книжки не надо заглядывать, уже наизусть выучила Розенталя. Я понимаю **происхождение и внутренний смысл этих правил** просто потому, что много времени занималась этим. **Время – это так важно?** Да, важно! Менделееву приснилась его таблица, потому что он день и ночь думал о ней.

Розенталь § 18. Обособленные определения. п.2.

//old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108

Примечание. Если после однородного определения-прилагательного употреблен причастный оборот [см. § 10, п. 7], то он **отделяется** от прилагательного запятой (но не выделяется запятыми с двух сторон); Его чёрная, ничем не прикрытая голова… так и мелькала в кустах (Т.).

Но если определительный оборот имеет **уточняющее значение** [см. § 22, п. 4], то он **обособляется** (выделяется запятыми с двух сторон): В утренней прохладе разлит горький запах полыни, смешанный с нежным, похожим на миндаль, ароматом повилики (Купр.).

Comment: *водя пальчиком* — думаю, Вы сознательно используете этот уничижительный стиль в отношении редакторов. Вам, вероятно, никогда не приходилось сталкиваться с авторами, самомнение которых обратно пропорционально уровню их грамотности. Завидую :)

Comment: В дополнении к ответу я привожу Правило Розенталя, в котором обособление оборота считается нормой и даже указано смысловое значение обособленного оборота. Поэтому не надо считать, что я не пользуюсь Правилами. Просто используя то или иное правило, да еще дополняя его собственной теорией, желательно знать его внутренний смысл, но для этого нужно дополнительно изучать грамматику и интонационные особенности различных конструкций. Знанием одних правил здесь не обойдешься. По тому, как человек применяет нормативные правила, хорошо видны его возможности в этом плане.

Comment: Судя по всему тут критикуют авторов, позволивших себе критиковать корректоров. Добалю свои пять копеек. Я с большим уважением отношусь к корректорам и редакторам вообще - и довольно неприязненно к большинству тех конкретных, с которыми сталкивался по жизни. Претензия, собственно, одна. Они все снобы - и смотрят на автора свысока. Возможно, просто не умеют иначе.

Comment: То есть когда находят пропущенную (реально пропущенную!) запятую - низкий им поклон. Но когда под своё прокрустово ложе правил подтягивают весь текст, в котором нихрена не смыслят - и при этом совершенно не склонны объяснить, зачем та или иная правка делается.... Вот тут у меня постоянно возникали конфликты...

Answer (score 2):

Определение *похожие на птичьи* относится к слову *голоса* и является согласованным. Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §46. Обособляются (выделяются или отделяются) запятыми определительные обороты, т.е. определения, выраженные причастиями или прилагательными с зависимыми словами, в следующих случаях.
>
> 1. Определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого существительного, выделяется или отделяется запятыми;
> 2. Определительный оборот, стоящий перед определяемым существительным, не отделяется запятой от определяемого слова; Однако определительный оборот, стоящий перед именем существительным, выделяется запятыми, если он осложнен обстоятельственным оттенком значения;
> 3. Определительный оборот выделяется запятыми, если он отделен от определяемого слова другими членами предложения.

В вашем случае определение стоит перед определяемым словом, вплотную к нему. Значения обстоятельства тут нет, поэтому требуется только запятая перед оборотом:

*Разочарованный, он ложился обратно на матрас, смотрел вниз из-под полей соломенной шляпы и слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи голоса.*

Возможно, что запятая поставлена для разрешения неоднозначности. Из-за того, что определение заканчивается словом *птичьи*, а определяемое слово *голоса* идет сразу после него, фразу можно воспринять двумя разными способами:

- *голоса* является определяемым словом для *похожие на птичьи*;
- *голоса* входит в состав определения *похожие на птичьи голоса*.

Без запятой требуется полностью прочитать фразу, убедиться в отсутствии определяемого слова для *тонкие* и *похожие на птичьи голоса*, и только после этого сделать вывод, что *голоса* были определяемым словом. С запятой полагаться на контекст для разрешения неоднозначности не требуется.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: "...и слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи голоса". Это ваш вариант, вам так удобно читать? Если к обороту добавить еще одно слово, то предложение вообще нельзя будет прочесть. Но всё равно не будем (по правилам) обособлять, да?  Пусть читают как хотят.

Comment: "без запятой предложение вообще нельзя будет прочесть" - Да уж как-нибудь человек сумеет прочесть. Конечно, придется попотеть, потужится, но победа интеллекта над разумом неизбежна.

Comment: А еще лучше так: «…слушал их тонкие голоса, которые были похожи на птичьи».  Неплохо, не правда ли,  еще понятнее стало. Нет, JKlen, вы не писатель, лучше бы вы этого не говорили, только под критику подставляетесь.  Вот беретесь рассуждать о темпе, который в этом фрагменте ничего не определяет.  Но так ли это? Интонация предложения строится на перечислении однородных членов, а вы этот ритм нарушаете тем, что целую фразу в конце прибавляете. И еще  меняете структуру, убираете второй план, «утяжеляете» конструкцию в целом.  Ничего, прочитают! В  одну линейку-то удобно читать.

Comment: Теперь  еще яснее стало, как вы  обращаетесь с художественной тканью  авторского произведения. Представьте, что вы подходите у художнику, смотрите на его работу и советуете тени с лица убрать, а то его плохо видно, или еще что-то в этом роде.  А сами последний раз рисовали только  в детском саду. Здесь примерно та же ситуация.

Comment: JKlen лично я никогда не обращал внимания на запятые при чтении, и это мне никогда не мешало, а скорее всего помогало. Но может быть вы правы и, изучив синтаксис, я начну читать намного продуктивнее? Думаю, это вряд ли. Просто, меня начнут отвлекать запятые, вот и вся разница )))

Comment: @JKlen Да ладно, извините, никуда я не перехожу.  Просто обобщаю ситуацию, НЕ ИМЕЯ В ВИДУ  лично и конкретно вас. Мой персонаж в этих комментариях очень хороший человек и в чем-то своем прекрасный специалист., но он не написал в своей жизни ни одного художественного произведения, даже маленького рассказика.  А без этого трудно понять и судить автора. Так что мои уважаемые друзья и оппоненты, главное - это повысмть скорость чтения. И чтобы никакого мистицизма. Кстати, кто меня постоянно минусует? Чисто из любопытства. Честный счет - это 2:2.

Comment: @Sharon, здравствуйте! Интересно здесь! А вы не получали мой детский вопрос в комментариях под вашим ответом здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463501/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-как-4  ?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Нет, я его не читала, там всё перепуталось, иначе ответила бы. конечно. Но он не кажется мне детским, интересный вопрос. Отвечу чуть позже.

Comment: Александр, отвечаю наконец на ваш вопрос. С одной стороны, запятая в СПП с одним придаточным ставится всегда, но при этом надо быть уверенным, что это именно придаточное предложение. Прежде всего, проверяется предикативная основа (у нас односоставное инфинитивное предложение), а потом следует обратиться к справочнику по синтаксису и проверить его структуру (общую схему, основные и дополнительные средства связи). В данном случае это СПП с изъяснительным придаточным, в качестве опорного слова используется существительное.

Comment: Такая проверка особенно важна, если есть основания подозревать, что это оборот с подчинительным союзом, а не предложение. Надо сказать, что подобные обороты по структуре очень похожи на придаточные предложения (делай что хочешь, делай  как знаешь), а отличаются они малой распространенностью и добавочным обобщенным значением. Но при распространении и придания им реального содержания они очень легко переходят в придаточные и обособляются.

Comment: В основном обороты относятся к глаголам, но есть и такие:  она чудо как хороша, он беда какой крутой. Что касается варианта «решение как действовать», то иногда появляется  желание назвать конструкцию ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ и не обособлять по аналогии с несогласованным определением (решение действовать), но такая практика не применяется. Например: «Решение, как действовать,  пришло мгновенно, в ту же минуту. Времени на раздумье не было». Обособление оборота здесь плохо вписывается в интонационную структуру предложения, замедляет динамику действия.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы не было запятой в конце, то фраза читалась бы совершенно по-другому. Предложение без запятой будто бы было не законченным. "...и слушал их тонкие, похожие на птичьи голоса..." И дальше хочется прочитать "Что?", "И слушал их тонкие... Что?.." Без запятой меняется смысл, и "голоса" на слух становятся просто частью сравнительного оборота. Тогда получается, что есть еще что-то, что похоже на птичьи голоса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне понятна ваша мысль. Я прокомментрую ее в своем втором ответе.

Answer (score 0):

```
Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений - явление достаточно
редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с
уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая
ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной - между определениями.

Кой-где выглянули женские, (какие именно?) большей частью старушечьи, головы (Тургенев).
```

[ссылка](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/42-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_uprazhneniya/stages/903-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)