# Грамматический ребус на корректное использование "как"

Tags: союзы, союзные-слова

Рассмотрим два предложения:

```
1. Решение такое, как нам надо. 
2. Решение такое, как нам надо иметь.
```

Корректно ли (2) и если нет, то почему?

Comment: В https://ruscorpora.ru/old/search-main.html оба не встречаются. Да и на google.ru тоже.

Comment: Все находится, да и зачем искать. все и так ясн
https://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=S&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%F2%E0%EA%EE%E9&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%EA%E0%EA&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&parent4=0&level4=0&min4=1&max4=2&lex4=%ED%E0%E4%EE&gramm4=&sem4=&sem-mod4=sem&sem-mod4=sem2&flags4=&m4=